# How to check if an array contains integer values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array dynamically getting generated which looks like below.

`["123", "" , "21345", "90"].["", "" , "", ""]`.

The array length dynamically gets generated but only contains integer values in it. How do i validate if the array contains integer values in it or an empty values array via JavaScript?

Comment: your array contains strings, not integer.

Comment: If string are valid numbers is what you are about to test, __`["123", "21345", "90"].every(Number);`__ It will fail with `0` though...

Comment: Iterate over the array and check each item

Comment: @Rayon Thanks ! I just learned `every()`

Comment: `var containsInteger = values.some(Number.isInteger)`

Comment: @Rayon, it fails with `'0'`.

Comment: @NinaScholz — I knew it was coming my way ;)

Comment: Am i missing something implementing the logic http://jsbin.com/gequvoxega/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the string is equal to a stringed implicid casted number.

```js
function isNumber(s) {
    return (+s).toString() === s;
}

console.log(["123", "", "21345", "90"].every(isNumber));
console.log(["123", "0", "21345", "90"].every(isNumber));
```